# store a javascript value to less variables + reactjs

Tags: reactjs, less

I am trying to fill less variable value with a js variable from an html page in reactjs based app.

index.html

```
<script>window.baseColor = '#000000'//Color value will be dynamic</script>
```

style.less

```
@baseColor: window.baseColor
```

Comment: Less is usually compiled to css before loading it to browser. so are you looking for css variable or are you looking for inline react styles ?

Comment: Do you think inline react styles is a correct way? Also there no way to update less variable from inside reactjs?

Comment: Less, scss etc.. are pre-processors meaning they will be compiled to css before browser can understand it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible but you can do it using inline style and if you are going to use it in multiple components you can use the new context API

```
const BaseColorContext = React.createContext('#000000')
class ColorProvider extends React.Component {
  state = {baseColor: '#fff'}
  render() {
    return (
      <BaseColorContext.Provider value={this.state.baseColor}>
        {this.props.children}
      </BaseColorContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ColorProvider>
        <BaseColorContext.Consumer>
          {val => <div style={{backgroundColor:val}}>content here</div>}
        </BaseColorContext.Consumer>
      </ColorProvider>
    )
  }
}
```